# No permission to call SpreadsheetApp.openById

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, permissions

The goal of this script is to pull the employee ID's corresponding to the Employee names from a different google worksheet. I expect that every time an Employee name is chosen from the drop down of a sheet, the employee ID would appear in the next cell.

```
function getEmployeeID(selectedName) {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById('codeID');
  var employeeDataSheet = spreadsheet.getSheetByName('Sheet1'); // Replace 'Sheet1' with the actual sheet name
  var dataRange = employeeDataSheet.getRange("B2:A" + employeeDataSheet.getLastRow()); // Column B                       for names and Column A for IDs
  var values = dataRange.getValues();

  for (var i = 0; i \< values.length; i++) {
    if (values\[i\]\[1\] == selectedName) {
      return values\[i\]\[0\]; // Return the ID if a match is found
    }
  }
  return "Employee ID not found"; // Return an error message if no match is found
}
```

I tried this and the error message that appears is as follows: You do not have permission to call SpreadsheetApp.openById. Required permission: https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets (line 2).

Comment: In your situation, how did you run your script? For example, although I'm not sure about your actual situation, I think that your script cannot be used with a custom function.

Answer (score 0):

If you're attempting to use this in a simple trigger like onEdit then move to an installable trigger and it will probably work.

```
function getEmployeeID(selectedName) {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById('codeID');
  var sh = spreadsheet.getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  var rg = sh.getRange("A2:B" + sh.getLastRow());
  var vs = rg.getValues();
  for (var i = 0; i < vs.length; i++) {
    if (vs[i][1] == selectedName) {
      return vs[i][0];
    }
  }
  return "Employee ID not found";
}
```

- [format code](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks)
- [google-apps-script reference](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference)
- [Learn More](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/google-apps-script/info)
- [Simple Trigger Restrictions](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers#restrictions)